# What is the proper way to mock a list inside a subscribe in Android? Is it even possible?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

I have the following question because I've been fairly stuck for a while.

I have the following array:

```
 private val toyGroupCodes = listOf("A1", "B2", "C3", "D4")
```

and I'm working with RxJava to obtain a list. I use the list to check if any of the toys inside it match the toyGroupCodes, see code below:

```
.subscribe ({ toyGroups: List<toyGroup?>? ->
            if (!toyGroups.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                if (toyGroups.any { it?.toyName in toyGroupCodes }) {
                    // do stuff
                } else {
                    // do other stuff
                }

            } else {
                // do other stuff
            }
        }, Timber::e)
```

The code works. The issue I'm having is that I have to write a proper test case. The struggle I'm facing is that my test specifically fails on this line:

```
toyGroups.any { it?.toyName in toyGroupCodes }
```

I've been trying all kinds of mocking to try and make it pass but I'm having no success. Is it because **toyGroups** is inside the subscribe that you can't mock it? If I comment out the if statement, the test passes. So I'm 100% sure the issue lies there. Is it because there's a collection iterable() happening through any{} that is not stubbed? If so, how can you solve this?

Can anybody help me please.

Comment: Personally, I struggled slightly with Unit testing without proper separation of concerns. And I found personally the best way to force myself into that was MVP. As you could mock the interface and check the times it called and what was passed to it. etc.